# Route Parameter in Resource Route - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I am creating an API route where some endpoints have ids in the route. I was hoping to do something like the following route but I'm not sure how to get the parameter when in the Resource Controller

```
Route::resource('plans','api\PlanController');
Route::resource('plans/{plan_id}/days','api\PlanDayController');
```

Is this possible, and if so how would I best make sure the Resource Controller filters the data to the correct plan_id as specified in the route? I would like to continue using the `Route::resource` as this forces consistent structure into the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nested resource routing, still exists, just not in the docs anymore.

`Route::resource('plans.days', 'api\PlanDayController');`

```
GET plans/{plan}/days
GET plans/{plan}/days/{day}
etc...
```

[Laravel Docs 5.1 - Nested Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-nested-resources)